# Failing to list files from azure blob storage using keyvault on java

Tags: java, azure, azure-keyvault

So im trying to list the files inside of an Azure Blob Storage. I'm able to do that using the connection string or access key from the blob storage but i dont want it to be leaked on the code so i tried to implement Azure Keyvault on the acess key and i'm now getting an authentication error(yes i do have enough permissions since i can run it without the keyvault). are there any workaround i've been trying alot but havent found a solution yet.

Heres the code snippet im using

```
package org.example;
import com.azure.storage.common.StorageSharedKeyCredential;
import com.azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder;
import com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClient;
import com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.SecretClientBuilder;
import com.azure.security.keyvault.secrets.models.KeyVaultSecret;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobContainerClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder;
import com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobItem;

public class ListKeyVaultSecrets {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String accountName = "";
        String containerName = "";
        String secretName = "";
        String keyVaultUrl = "";


        SecretClient secretClient = new SecretClientBuilder()
                .vaultUrl(keyVaultUrl)
                .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
                .buildClient();



        KeyVaultSecret secret = secretClient.getSecret(secretName); ## the error is here###
        String accountKey = secret.getValue();                       ###################

        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
                .endpoint(String.format("https://%s.blob.core.windows.net", accountName))
                .credential(new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey))
                .buildClient();


        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(containerName);


        for (BlobItem blobItem : containerClient.listBlobs()) {
            System.out.println(blobItem.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

At the end im getting this error btw:

```
[main] INFO com.azure.identity.ChainedTokenCredential - Azure Identity => Attempted credential EnvironmentCredential is unavailable.
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] INFO com.azure.identity.ChainedTokenCredential - Azure Identity => Attempted credential ManagedIdentityCredential is unavailable.
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] INFO com.azure.identity.ChainedTokenCredential - Azure Identity => Attempted credential SharedTokenCacheCredential is unavailable.
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] ERROR com.azure.identity.implementation.WindowsCredentialAccessor - Elemento não encontrado.
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] INFO com.azure.identity.ChainedTokenCredential - Azure Identity => Attempted credential IntelliJCredential is unavailable.
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] ERROR com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClient - 'az' n�o � reconhecido como um comando internoou externo, um programa oper�vel ou um arquivo em lotes.
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] ERROR com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClient - 'az' n�o � reconhecido como um comando internoou externo, um programa oper�vel ou um arquivo em lotes.
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] ERROR com.azure.core.implementation.AccessTokenCache - Failed to acquire a new access token.
[parallel-1] INFO com.azure.identity.ChainedTokenCredential - Azure Identity => Attempted credential EnvironmentCredential is unavailable.
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] INFO com.azure.identity.ChainedTokenCredential - Azure Identity => Attempted credential ManagedIdentityCredential is unavailable.
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] INFO com.azure.identity.ChainedTokenCredential - Azure Identity => Attempted credential SharedTokenCacheCredential is unavailable.
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] ERROR com.azure.identity.implementation.WindowsCredentialAccessor - Elemento não encontrado.
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] INFO com.azure.identity.ChainedTokenCredential - Azure Identity => Attempted credential IntelliJCredential is unavailable.
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] ERROR com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClient - 'az' n�o � reconhecido como um comando internoou externo, um programa oper�vel ou um arquivo em lotes.
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] ERROR com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClient - 'az' n�o � reconhecido como um comando internoou externo, um programa oper�vel ou um arquivo em lotes.
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] ERROR com.azure.core.implementation.AccessTokenCache - Failed to acquire a new access token.
[parallel-2] INFO com.azure.identity.ChainedTokenCredential - Azure Identity => Attempted credential EnvironmentCredential is unavailable.
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] INFO com.azure.identity.ChainedTokenCredential - Azure Identity => Attempted credential ManagedIdentityCredential is unavailable.
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] INFO com.azure.identity.ChainedTokenCredential - Azure Identity => Attempted credential SharedTokenCacheCredential is unavailable.
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] ERROR com.azure.identity.implementation.WindowsCredentialAccessor - Elemento não encontrado.
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] INFO com.azure.identity.ChainedTokenCredential - Azure Identity => Attempted credential IntelliJCredential is unavailable.
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] ERROR com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClient - 'az' n�o � reconhecido como um comando internoou externo, um programa oper�vel ou um arquivo em lotes.
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] ERROR com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClient - 'az' n�o � reconhecido como um comando internoou externo, um programa oper�vel ou um arquivo em lotes.
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] ERROR com.azure.core.implementation.AccessTokenCache - Failed to acquire a new access token.
[parallel-3] INFO com.azure.identity.ChainedTokenCredential - Azure Identity => Attempted credential EnvironmentCredential is unavailable.
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] INFO com.azure.identity.ChainedTokenCredential - Azure Identity => Attempted credential ManagedIdentityCredential is unavailable.
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] INFO com.azure.identity.ChainedTokenCredential - Azure Identity => Attempted credential SharedTokenCacheCredential is unavailable.
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] ERROR com.azure.identity.implementation.WindowsCredentialAccessor - Elemento não encontrado.
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] INFO com.azure.identity.ChainedTokenCredential - Azure Identity => Attempted credential IntelliJCredential is unavailable.
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] ERROR com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClient - 'az' n�o � reconhecido como um comando internoou externo, um programa oper�vel ou um arquivo em lotes.
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] ERROR com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClient - 'az' n�o � reconhecido como um comando internoou externo, um programa oper�vel ou um arquivo em lotes.
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] ERROR com.azure.core.implementation.AccessTokenCache - Failed to acquire a new access token.
[main] ERROR com.azure.core.http.policy.RetryPolicy - {"az.sdk.message":"Retry attempts have been exhausted.","exception":"DefaultAzureCredential authentication failed. ---> AzureCliCredential authentication failed. Error Details: 'az' n�o � reconhecido como um comando internoou externo, um programa oper�vel ou um arquivo em lotes.","tryCount":3}
[main] ERROR com.azure.core.http.policy.RetryPolicy - DefaultAzureCredential authentication failed. ---> AzureCliCredential authentication failed. Error Details: 'az' n�o � reconhecido como um comando internoou externo, um programa oper�vel ou um arquivo em lotes.
[main] ERROR com.azure.core.implementation.http.rest.RestProxyBase - DefaultAzureCredential authentication failed. ---> AzureCliCredential authentication failed. Error Details: 'az' n�o � reconhecido como um comando internoou externo, um programa oper�vel ou um arquivo em lotes.

I've tried most of the solutions on the documentation but it doesnt seem to work for some reason.
```

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

> ERROR com.azure.core.http.policy.RetryPolicy -
> {"az.sdk.message":"Retry attempts have been
> exhausted.","exception":"DefaultAzureCredential authentication failed. ---> AzureCliCredential authentication failed. Error Details: 'az' n o   reconhecido como um comando internoou externo, um programa oper vel ou um arquivo em lotes.","tryCount":3}

The above error occurs when you attempt to authenticate using various credentials, including **`EnvironmentCredential, ManagedIdentityCredential, SharedTokenCacheCredential, and IntelliJCredential`**. Still, none of them are available or are failing to authenticate and also there is az command is not installed yet.

You can install the az cli commands using this [MS-DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?tabs=azure-cli) and you need to use **`az login`** command before running the code in your terminal.

You can use the below code to get the list of files from Azure blob storage without using the connection string and account key.

**Code:**

```
import com.azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredential;
import com.azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobContainerClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder;
import com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobItem;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String containerName = "test2";
        DefaultAzureCredential defaultCredential = new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build();
// Azure SDK client builders accept the credential as a parameter
       BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
            .endpoint("https://<storageaccountname>.blob.core.windows.net/")
            .credential(defaultCredential)
            .buildClient();
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        for (BlobItem blobItem : containerClient.listBlobs()) {
            System.out.println(blobItem.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Also, You need **`storage blob data contributor role`** to access the data from Azure blob storage.

**Reference:**
[Quickstart: Azure Blob Storage library - Java | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-java?tabs=powershell%2Cmanaged-identity%2Croles-azure-portal%2Csign-in-azure-cli#authenticate-to-azure-and-authorize-access-to-blob-data)